# Unit Test Spring-boot Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Is there anyway to write unit test for my RestController without mocking the service using @MockBean?

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private CarService carService;


@Test
public void shouldReturnCarDetails() {

    //when(carService.getCarDetails(1)).thenReturn(new Car(1, 300));
    try {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/cars/1")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("speed").value(300));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

Comment: Can you specify what issue you have with your current implementation?

Comment: I heard about classist approch that they don't use mocks and i wonder how i can implement it in this case

Comment: are you looking for integration tests?

Comment: So you don't want to write a unit test, but instead you want an integration test, testing your complete application? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907132/junit-beforeall-not-working/50907848#50907848 -: This will help you to write integration test.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option called, @EnableWebMvc / mockMvc through which you can test your controller layer.

Code snippet given below,

```
/*
 * The TransactionsControllerTest class implements Junit functionality that
 * simply connect to the controller layer (TransactionsController) and test the
 * controller layer with some pre-defined/test value. This class also provides
 * the details result for each test cases.
 * 
 * @author Sibsankar Bera
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 2018-08-31
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TransactionsController.class, AppConfig.class, AppInitializer.class })
@EnableWebMvc
public class TransactionsControllerTest {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TransactionsControllerTest.class.getName());
    private MockMvc mockMvc = null;
    String values = null;

    @InjectMocks
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    /**
     * This Junit test method assigns required resources value before use.
     */
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        values = TransactionConstant.AUTHORIZATION_CODE;
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    /**
     * This Junit test method is used to test controller layer api,
     * "/transactions/getAllTransactionList"
     */
    @Test
    public void getAllTransactionList_Test() {
        try {
            logger.info("Logger Name: getAllTransactionList_Test() :: " + logger.getName());
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/getAllTransactionList").header("authorization_code", values))
                    .andReturn();
            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
            JsonNode resultNodes = root.path("result");
            logger.debug("Junit Response :: resultNodes :: getAllTransactionList_Test() :: " + resultNodes.asText());
            assertEquals(resultNodes.asText(), "success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Junit :: Exception :: getAllTransactionList_Test() ::  ", e);
        }
    }
```